# Regex: match character which has a even amount of backslashes before it

Tags: java, regex

I need a RegEx which matches a certain character if before this character are a event amount of (or none) backslashes.

For Example:

```
*       #match the character *
\*      #no match
\\*     #match the character *
\\\*    #no match
\\\\*   #match the character *
```

I've tried the following RegEx: `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\*` but it matches the whole sequence (e.g. `\\*`) and not just the character `*`.

Here is my playground: https://regex101.com/r/2HLpY0/1

Comment: Are you trying to use it in a `split` method?

Comment: Need to see actual code you're using: Sometimes the backslash character is eaten by the programming language's _own_ string literal parser and doesn't even get to the regex, that is, "\\" might be seen to the regex engine as "\" not "\\" and "\*" might be seen as "*".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not necessarily, I'm using it currently in a `replaceAll` but I might also need it in a `split` method in the future.

Comment: Another tip might be to give up on the lookahead regexes (except the one that forbids the odd number of backslashes and match the lone `'*'` as a matching group (i.e., inside of parens).  And use `[\]` to match backslash or `[*]` to match a star - give up on "quoting" the special chars. (i.e., don't need to "quote" special chars inside of a character group matcher `[]`

Comment: In `replaceAll`, no need to avoid consuming them. Use a capturing group: `replaceAll("((?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*)\\*", "$1")`

Comment: @davidbak it's not really about java or the programming language if the result is correct here: https://regex101.com/r/2HLpY0/1 it'll be also correct in my code.

Comment: You could try matching `^(\\\\)*\*` if the matching group is at the start of a line

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I figured this out too, but I'm not quite happy with this solution, it feels like this can be solved better.

Comment: @Met Not in Java. With PCRE, `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K\*` is the solution. In .NET, `(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)\*` will work - not sure it will in Java.

Comment: No - the language adds the complexity that you are specifying the regex inside of a string literal - and different language have different rules about quoting-special-characters-using-backslashes inside of string literals. The online regex testers do _not_ have that additional layer of complexity.  (And the string literals have _different_ special characters than the regex, and different languages have different rules about what happens if you backslash quote a character that is _not_ a special character.)

Comment: @davidbak alright, my testcode looks like this:
`"\\\\\\\\*\\\\\\*".replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*\\*", "REPLACEMENT")`
The first `*` should be replaces with the string `REPLACEMENT` and the last `*` should not be replaced

Comment: @Met please look up how Java string literals treat the backslash character.  Just as an example, when you write `"(?<!\\)("` the first backslash _in the string literal_ quotes the second, thus the regex engine sees `(?<!\(` - so the backslash _that the regex engine sees_ is no longer quoting a backslash - it's quoting a different regex special character, the left paren.

Comment: @davidbakI had a few copy and paste troubles with the code, you may saw a incorrect version. The current edit of my answer above is the actual code.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.  It just...doesn't...make sense.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, you might be right. Both of your Regex are working as expected but as Java isn't supporting it, it can't be helped...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unbounded, and I don't know the exact context in which you plan to use the regex.  Assuming you literally want to match just an entire string consisting of an even or odd number of backslashes, followed by some content, then you may use the pattern:

```
(?<=\s|^)(?:\\{2})*(\*)(?=\s|$)
```

This will match only with an even number of leading backslashes.  I use a formal pattern matcher below, because it lets us gracefully handle the case where no match is found.

```
String input = "Hello World! \\\\\\\\* more content here? \\\\*";
String pattern = "(?<=\\s|^)(?:\\\\{2})*(\\*)(?=\\s|$)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);

boolean found = false;
while (m.find()) {
    found = true;
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("No match");
}
```

**Output:**

```
*
*
(two asterisks found in the input)
```

Note that using `String#replaceAll` is not as nice as above, because it would return the original input string in the case of no match.

Comment: Although your answer isn't solving my problem, I haven't downvoted your solution.

Comment: Um...it _is_ solving your problem from what I can see.  If I am missing some requirement, you should speak up and say what that is.

Comment: Your regex is matching also the whole sequence like mine, but it groups it, so that the first group is the match I'm searching for. The goal / requirement is to match only the character specified.

Comment: My pattern is only matching the single `*` character, which you may replace with whatever you want.  I have edited my answer a few times, and maybe you need to reload the page.

Comment: If your pattern would match only the `*` character, then this line `"\\\\*".replaceAll("(?<=\\s|^)(?:\\\\{2})*(\\*)(?=\\s|$)", "_")` should return `\\_` but it returns `_` because your pattern is matching the whole sequence.

Comment: @Met The replace all option is not a good one for several reasons.  First, it is hard to detect a negative match.  Second, most likely the OP wants to search for his pattern in some larger text, which my answer allows.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer isn't solving my problem. You just create your own rules to justify.